# Can't assign struct element as a Google/uuid data type

Tags: postgresql, go, uuid

I am using https://github.com/google/uuid in my project and I want my User Struct to have an id with as a UUID but It will not let me assign it as the data type. When I try to it gives me the error `syntax error: unexpected :, expecting type`. Here is my code for reference:

```
package postgres

import (
  "time"
  "github.com/google/uuid"
)

type DbUser struct {
  ID: uuid.UUID,
  Username: string,
  Password: string,
  Email: string,
  DateOfBirth: time,
  dateCreated: time, 
}
```

Can anyone help me clarify the syntax for passing a struct element or variable as a UUID?

Comment: Remove the `:` and `,` from the type definition. Both `:` and `,` are used in composite literals, e.g. when initializing a struct value, not in struct type definitions.

Comment: lol my bad I spent like a while reading the UUID docs thinking I messed something up with it when really I messed up the struct itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your [struct definition](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) is wrong, you're using the syntax for a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals).
It should be:

```
type DbUser struct {
  ID uuid.UUID
  Username string
  Password string
  Email string
  DateOfBirth time.Time
  dateCreated time.Time
}
```

Also note that `time` is not a type, it's a package name.

You may want to take the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org) to learn the basic syntax.

Comment: lol sorry its had been a long day of programming when I posted this question and I recently took a 2-month break from this giant Go project that I started this year so I kinda forgot that when defining stucts : is not used as its only used in instantating the struct

Answer (score 0):

time is the package name ,it could not be defined the field,you should use time.Time.

```
import (
      "time"
      "github.com/google/uuid"
    )
    
    type DbUser struct {
        ID          uuid.UUID
        Username    string
        Password    string
        Email       string
        DateOfBirth time.Time
        dateCreated time.Time
    }
```